# AngularJS Test a Factory with Mocha

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am new to Mocha and AngularJS Unit Testing but want to test my application using Mocha.  I have basic language tests working, but I cannot run tests against my applications Factory or Controller.

I have the following basic files.

apps.js

```
aangular.module('MyApp', []);
```

file1.js

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory('Factory1' ...);
```

file2.js

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory('Factory2' ...);
angular.module('MyApp').factory('Controller' ...);

describe('Main Test', function() {
    var FactoryToTest;
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_Factory_) {
        FactoryToTest = _Factory_;
    }));

    describe('Factory2', function () {
        it('should return "unknown"', function () {
            Game = {};
            expect(new Factory2(Game)).to.equal('unknown');
        });
    });
});
```

When I run the test, it generates an error, and I am not sure what to fix to get this to work.

Error:

```
Message:
    object is not a function
Stack:
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Suite.<anonymous> (b:\app\test.js:5:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because the beforeEach function should take a callback function instead of an object. According to the [Angular guide on module unit testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) (scroll to bottom of the page) :

> Each module can only be loaded once per injector. Usually an Angular app has only one injector and modules are only loaded once. Each test has its own injector and modules are loaded multiple times.